# Change datatype of tensors from checkpoint or frozen graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have deeplabv3 frozen graph. There are some tensors in this graph. for example

ImageTensor  =>  (<tf.Tensor 'ImageTensor:0' shape=(1, ?, ?, 3) dtype=uint8>,)
Squeeze  =>  (<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(?, ?, 3) dtype=uint8>,)

I want to change the dtype from uit8 to float32 and save the modified graph. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly how your deeplabv3 graph works, but if you just want to convert a tensor to a different type, you can use `tf.cast()`.